# Django: as_view: How does cls and initkwargs are passed to view function

Tags: django

I am trying to understand the `as_view` code for Class based views. I see

```
self = cls(**initkwargs)
```

How the view function get `cls` and `initkwargs`

I have put an image to mean what I want to ask

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not. Both `cls` and `initkwargs` come from `as_view`'s arguments.
The attribute assignments that happen to the `view` function are meant for later processing.

Comment: Can you explain later where they are used. So everytime the url is called, as_view() will be run.

Comment: In current main branch `.view_class` is used in resolving URLs; for the detailed error pages in debug mode and for admin docs. `.view_initkwargs` seems to not be used anywhere. I can't find functional references to either in older versions. Both attributes have been added in Django 1.9, according to docs